# Sending Email in Sugarcrm takes long time

Tags: sugarcrm

When I am trying to send an email with the attachment it gives the below error. We are using SugarCRM Community Edition 6.5 hosted on Local Server. Using Gmail.

> Warning: mime_content_type() [function.mime-content-type]: File or
>   path not found
>   'cache/modules/Emails/1/6bbf0a1c-c58b-a96e-6759-576ecd00f639' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SugarCrm\modules\Emails\Email.php on line 335
>       Warning: mime_content_type() [function.mime-content-type]: File or path not found
>   'cache/modules/Emails/1/6bbf0a1c-c58b-a96e-6759-576ecd00f639' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SugarCrm\modules\Emails\Email.php on line 335
>   {"composeLayoutId":"composeLayout0"}

Lines at 335 are

```
function sendEmailTest($mailserver_url, $port, $ssltls, $smtp_auth_req, $smtp_username, $smtppassword, $fromaddress, $toaddress, $mail_sendtype = 'smtp', $fromname = '') {
global $current_user,$app_strings;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are only warnings.
Before sending email please try to verify the **Email Settings** and  also send test email from Email Settings page.

Comment: Hi , Email with templates is going but when documents attached it doe not go